# Sub-Query Returns More than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a subquery in my SELECT statement that returns more than one row, but I need both values.  Is there anyway to concatenate the multiple values with a comma to make the outside query think the subquery is only returning one value?

Example of my query:

```
select o.id,
   (select v.value v from values v join attributes a on v.att_id=a.att_id where a.att_id='100' and v.id=o.id)
from objects o
where o.class_id='GGzX';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks Don, trying to figure out if that post will work with my subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this query, maybe will be useful (click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54346/1) to test the query):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1(
ID INT);

CREATE TABLE TEST2(
    ID INT,
    TXT VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES(3);

INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(1,'A');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(1,'B');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(2,'C');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(3,'A');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(3,'B');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES(3,'C');

/* HERE IS THE QUERY!!!*/
SELECT A.ID, 
(SELECT listagg(B.TXT,',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.ID)
FROM TEST2 B WHERE B.ID = A.ID
) AS CONTATENATED_FIELD
FROM TEST1 A;
```

NOTE: listagg works in 11.X versions, please see this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm) for more information.

According with your query maybe you need something like this:

```
select o.id,
(SELECT listagg(v.value,',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.value) from values v join attributes a on v.att_id=a.att_id where a.att_id='100' and v.id=o.id)
from objects o
where o.class_id='GGzX';
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying per Don's suggestion thru an alternate post, however my "B.txt" is actually a sub query.  Can you use LISTAGG with a subquery?

Comment: Nevermind I see what you did there...looks like it works initially...

Comment: Anyway, i would recommend you try to get out this subquery.

Comment: Your example in the 2nd code block worked perfectly...thanks

Comment: You're welcome, do not forget, if possible avoid complex subqueries, in this case, maybe you can extract the joins in the subquery, and put outside it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `GROUP BY a.att_id` or limit your query

```
select o.id,
   (select v.value val from values v join attributes a on v.att_id=a.att_id
 where a.att_id='100' and v.id=o.id GROUP BY a.att_id)
from objects o
where o.class_id='GGzX';

OR


select o.id,
   (select v.value val from values v join attributes a on v.att_id=a.att_id
 where a.att_id='100' and v.id=o.id LIMIT 1)
from objects o
where o.class_id='GGzX';
```

OR just group the values by any seperator

```
select o.id,
   (select group_concat( v.value SEPARATOR ' / ') val from values v join attributes a on v.att_id=a.att_id
 where a.att_id='100' and v.id=o.id GROUP BY a.att_id)
from objects o
where o.class_id='GGzX';
```

Comment: actually my goal is to get the multiple values into one row, kind of as if my sub query is returning one value

Comment: See my updated answer `group_concat` query will do this job

Answer (score 0):

try `COALESCE`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

example found here ... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d7a8ccf0-1a40-4068-b6b4-dc568c1cc165/select-query-with-multiple-row-coalesce-subquery